# can't find jconsole in directory path java

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, jmx, jconsole

I installed Cassandra 4 on vm, then I want to use jconsole to monitor it, but I can't find the jconsole directory.

According to the documentation, it is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jconsole`. After I searched it was not there.

This is my `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which operating system is that vm running?

Comment: i use Oracle Linux Server 7.8

Comment: I'm not familiar with that distro but I *think* you can find it under `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_version/bin` (where `version` could or could not be there and, of course, is variable)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're referring to is talking about Oracle Java, whereas you've installed OpenJDK. jconsole will be living in a different folder.

at the commandline, try `ls -la $(which jconsole)` to see where it is located. assuming the JDK installed the binaries in the "usual" places.

Comment: I've done the command you mean, but it's still not there, btw thanks for advice